# TypeScript interface to cover Array and Typed Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, typed-arrays

I'd like to use TypeScript to declare functions with parameters that can be either a regular JavaScript Array, or a Typed Array, but I can't find a nice way to do it.  I was hoping that an interface like:

```
interface IArray
{
    length: number;
    [index: number]: number;
};
```

would let me declare a function:

```
declare var vAdd: { (a: IArray, b: IArray): IArray; };
```

and use it in any of the following ways:

```
var y;
y = vAdd(new Float32Array([1,2,3]), new Float32Array([1,2,3]));
y = vAdd([1,2,3], new Float32Array([1,2,3]));
y = vAdd(new Float32Array([1,2,3]), new Array(1,2,3));
```

... etc.  However, only the first line here works (in the TypeScript playground, at least).  The others generate an error saying the arguments don't match the function signature.

By overloading the function it can be made to work:

```
declare var vAdd: { (a: IArray, b: IArray): IArray;
                    (a: number[], b: IArray): IArray;
                    (a: IArray, b: number[]): IArray; 
                    (a: number[], b: number[]): IArray; };
```

but I'm wondering if there is a way I can avoid writing out all combinations of IArray and number[], which will get even more tedious for functions with more parameters.  Or is there something fundamentally wrong with what I'm trying to do?

Comment: The reference doc for TypeScript mentions that array literals are not yet treated as instances of the Array interface, which explains why the second line gives an error.  As for the 3rd line, it seems `new Array()` is also considered to return `any[]`, and not an instance of Array.

Comment: INaming of interfaces is a C# thing. Please keep the I off the name, interfaces are used in rather different context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Possible to define indexer interface for number[]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13074851/possible-to-define-indexer-interface-for-number)

There is a bug in the current ts release that doesnt allow indexer interfaces to compile and work as expected against native object arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the reference.  Unfortunately, even removing the indexer declaration from the IArray interface doesn't change either of the errors.

Comment: Your [codeplex bug](http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/331) is marked as 'Low' impact, which is surprising.  I voted it up and commented.  It's definitely the main thing stopping this working.  (BTW, I'll be sure to upvote your answer when I get enough rep)

Comment: FWIW, the 'Impact' field on CodePlex is not something the TypeScript team is looking at when prioritizing bugs. I believe 99% of the bugs are currently Impact 'Low' even though that's definitely not the case.