# Are object index signatures are equivalent to array types?

Tags: typescript

Section 3.5.4 of the spec states: "An array type of the form ElementType[] is equivalent to an object type with the index signature [index: number]: ElementType" but this does not appear to be the case e.g.

```
var a: {[index: number]: string;};
var b: string[];
a = ['1','2'];  // ERROR: Cannot convert 'string[]' to '{ [index: number]: string; }'
b = ['1','2'];  // OK
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Possible to define indexer interface for number\[\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13074851/possible-to-define-indexer-interface-for-number)

Comment: Work item: http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/331

Comment: I think you are correct, it's the same problem (indexed types are not equivalent to Arrays), seemingly contrary to the spec. I could only get my example assignment to work with a cast: `<any>a = ['1','2'];`

Answer (score 1):

Yep, this is a known bug in the compiler. It'll be fixed in a future release. The best workaround is a cast (on either side of the assignment - `a = <string[]>['1', '2']` probably looks slightly less weird).